# Doing a probability test using a data frame with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, probability

I want to preform a probability test of a large data set using a loop. I know how to do the calculation, but I want to do it as a test. (like a random "flipping the coin" test)
with this fake df:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([
['Alex',12, 'Apple'],['Bob',10, 'Banana'],['Clark',13, 'Citrus'], 
['Diana', 11, 'Banana'], ['Elisa', 13, 'Apple']
],columns=['Name','Age', 'Fruit'])
```

how do I create a loop randomly picking one name and get the probability of getting the fruit "Banana" ?
I am thinking somewhere in the line with:

```
experiments = 10000
bananas = 0
for i in range(experiments):
    for draw in range(1):
        result = df[df['Fruit']=='Banana'][random.randrange(len(df))]
        if result=='Banana':
            bananas += 1 

bananas/experiments
```

With the outcome being something close to 0,4 as that is what the probability is..

It obviously doesn't work, but I hope you understand what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do this using `sample` and `value_counts`:

```
df.sample(n=1000, replace=True)['Fruit'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Output:

```
Banana    0.418
Apple     0.387
Citrus    0.195
Name: Fruit, dtype: float64
```

To get the value for Banana just index select from the pd.Series:

```
df.sample(n=1000, replace=True)['Fruit'].value_counts(normalize=True)['Banana']
```

Output:

```
.418
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but isn't really what I was looking for. If I don't want the other variables, only bananas could I?